# Using Displace Modifier Textures on shading nodes

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders, displacement, shader-nodes

It may be a stupid question but I cannot figure out how to do it: I like a texture that is specifically in the texture tab of the Displace Modifier (Modifier only) but I'd like to use that texture in my shading nodes set-up to speed up and simplify my work but I really don't know how to do it, and if it is possible to of course.

Comment: I think it's not possible, but maybe you could try to do the same with the textures. You could also bake a displace modifier texture but it's a bit painful

Comment: Yeah, I don’t think one really can do that, but you can effectively duplicate it by mimicking its coordinate system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the best you can do in 2.9 as far as I know:

- In texture properties, switch the mode to *Brush* and make the texture.  Give it a name, or not.

[image: Texture properties showing a clouds brush]

- In the shader editor, create a material.  Don't do anything to it yet.
- In the 3D ViewPort switch to *Texture Paint*
- In the side bar, in the *Tool* tab, select mode *Material*
- Add a texture with the + button

[image: setting up the material texture]

If you look at your material in the shader editor you will see that this material has been hooked up to the color input of the principled shader node.

- Paint away.
- Remember to save all images.

I don't think that will simplify your work, alas.

Comment: It helped! Thanks :)